# How to use a field's value as an array index in $addFields stage (aggregation)

Tags: mongodb, pipeline, aggregation

I have a string in an array which is inside another array. I would like to concatenate another string with to the already-existing string (which is at the last index of both arrays). I have the indexes of the last elements store in the document

```
{
  _id: 'id',
  array1: [
    0: [...]
    ...
    m: [
      0: {}
      ...
      n: {id: 'id', string: 'hello'}
    ]
  ],
  i: m,
  j: n
}
```

I want to concatenate ' world!' to the string at `array1[m][n].string` or, in other words, to `array1[$i][$j].string`

I have already tried the following stages, but none have worked.

```
{ $addFields: { array1.$i.$j.string: <expression> }
{ $addFields: { array1.$[i].$[j].string: <expression> }
{ $addFields: { array1.[$i].[$j].string: <expression> }
```

**Data**

```
{
  _id: 'abc',
  array1: [
    0: {
      id: 'def'
      array2: [
        0: {
          id: '123',
          string: 'hello'
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  i: 0,
  j: 0,
}
```

After running the pipeline, I'd like to get the same structure but with 'hello world' in the string.

```
{
  _id: 'abc',
  array1: [
    0: {
      id: 'def'
      array2: [
        0: {
          id: '123',
          string: 'hello world'
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  i: 0,
  j: 0,
}
```

Comment: Add some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: Is the above one enough to understand the structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to modify multiple nested arrays, the one of the approach is to `$unwind` them, modify the data as your requirement and finally aggregate the unwinded data.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{"$unwind":"$array1"},
{"$unwind":"$array1.array2"},
{"$project":{
    _id:1,
    "array1.id":1,
    "array1.array2.id":1,
    "array1.array2.string":{"$concat":["$array1.array2.string","world"]}

    }
},
{
 "$group": {
  "_id": {"obj_id": "$_id", "arr1_id": "$array1.id"},
  "array2":{$push:"$array1.array2"}
 }
},
{
 "$group": {
  "_id": {"obj_id": "$_id.obj_id"},
  "array1":{"$push":{"id":"$_id.arr1_id", "array2": "$array2"}}
 }
}

])
```

Comment: This might not be very efficient, but it does the job. Thanks!